in Diameter Protocol Does a DRA need to show all the relevant applications or just relay application?
When creating a DRA (Diameter Routing Agent), in the CER/CEA do you need to have all the relevant Applications that the DRA allows or is the Relay Application (4294967295) enough?
I managed to get a connection between my HSS and DRA, trying get the traffic over now
